# Issue with calling function in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I was following optional values tutorial, in which we have following method

```
  func findIndexOfString (string : String, array : String[]) -> Int?{           
            for (index, value) in enumerate(array){             
                if(value == string){
                    return index
                }               
            }           
            return nil          
        }
```

however if i call this method by

```
let indexFound = findIndexOfString("myString", neighbour) //neighbour is array of String
```

give error that "Missing argument label ''array" in call , means i have to call this by

```
let indexFound = findIndexOfString("myString", array:neighbour)
```

Is it made compulsory to mention argument label in call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yeah**. It is compulsory for for `class methods`. You should use the parameter names except for the first parameter. There comes the difference between the class methods and functions, for functions you will not use(You cant unless function defines an external parameter name) the parameter names.

Comment: In tutorial, they could use let indexFound = findIndexOfString("myString", neighbour), without label

Comment: If they are using like that, it could be a function(outside of the class) not a method